# Running a simple docker container does not show up in "docker ps"

Tags: docker

I have a very simple docker container.

test.py

```
print("hallo world")
```

DockerFile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
    
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
    
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]
```

Everything builds without problems. However when I run `docker run <CONTAINER_NAME>` nothing happens not even an error message. And if I run `docker ps` afterward I don't see any containers running...

I want to have the container running, and be able to use commands such as python3 test.py

Comment: do you see anything after running `docker ps -a`?

Comment: The container runs a single process, then exits.  If you set `CMD python3 ./test.py` and remove the `ENTRYPOINT`, then when you `docker run` your container it will run your script.  There's not really value in "keeping the container alive" as a first-class goal, separate from the process it runs.

Answer (score 4):

If you run `docker container ls --all` you may discover that your container is **terminated** because its role is only to print a string, then terminate itself.

For that reason you cannot see it by `docker ps`.